# Can a modification of an existing method be still named original resarch

Tags: research-process, research-proposal

I have found a method in Computer Sciences that I have modified to solve some subject related problems. Are those tweaks of existing methods still be considered as original research? Or is it just hacking and crafting of those methods?

I am asking because the criterion 'original' is quite important in Sciences. And also useful for writing grants and research proposals

Comment: Hard to say. It depends on what exactly you have done. The word "modification" could be used for both things that I'd consider "original" and things that I wouldn't. Also it probably makes sense to use "original" in a graded manner, i.e., what you have done could be a bit original but not that much, rather than binary "either something is original or not".

Comment: @ChristianHennig, that would be a pretty good answer.

Comment: @Buffy I don't think so, it doesn't really answer the question (it can also be interpreted as a request for more details;-).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on (i.e. stealing from) a comment of Christian Hennig, the answer is yes, it can be, but it may not be. It is a judgement call by those who evaluate your work, such as reviewers at a journal.

The fact that you use a modification of some technique (or even the original technique) to solve some "interesting", problem would be the key, not the technique itself, in most cases.

If I were reviewing, I'd look at whether your work provides some insight into a class of problems that can result in future advances. Perhaps you had an insight that a, possibly, minor change had a big effect. That might be important. The nature of the problem solved would be important, especially if it is a problem that has been seeking a solution for a while.

But a small delta resulting in a small epsilon probably wouldn't be very interesting and thus, not very "original".

So, to make your own evaluation, think about the insight it provides, and think about the problem it solves. Small things can add up to big results, but it isn't guaranteed. And, again noting Christian Hennig, it isn't a binary thing, but a range of possibilities requiring judgement to evaluate.